# Why is my Briggs-Rauscher reaction oscillating but failing to turn blue?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

As the title says, I've constructed a Briggs-Rauscher reaction according to the ever-popular "Chemical Demonstration: A Handbook for Teachers of Chemistry" by B.Z. Shakhashiri (the same procedure is available on MIT OCW here: https://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/chemistry/demonstrations/videos/briggs-rauscher-reaction/briggs_rauscher.pdf and can be seen below)

Putting the three solutions together in the correct 1:1:1 ratio and stirring it vigorously turns the solution dark yellow as expected, but it does not turn dark blue, merely "resetting" to transparency and oscillating again from there.

What could be causing this? Since the blue is caused by the starch-triiodide complex, I assume my starch solution is too dilute, and that adding some more starch to the third solution may help, but I will not be able to test any solutions until Friday, since it is part of a class. Has anyone else had the same issues?

[image: LIST OF MATERIALS]

[image: PROCEDURE]

Comment: Questions on CH SE should be rather self-contained, using links just as the further reference, not needed for understanding the question.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know, I've edited the post now to include the MIT OCW procedure and materials.

Comment: Ehm, for future reference, it is preferred to copy/paste or retype essential quotes as text, in the scope needed to understand the question. // The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.

Comment: Try with another source of starch. I have seen starch samples for potatoes that do not react with iodine.

Comment: Does MIT offer these materials altogether with a contact address (e.g.; to receive comments/suggestions for improvement of the material, the addition of experiments)?  Possibly they could provide additional information, too.